# Alternatives to ora_rowscn in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a third party Oracle database that is queried periodically to copy some data tables into a Microsoft database. We care about changes to the Oracle data, and need to keep it in sync with our copy.

The code to copy relies on ORA_ROWSCN to determine which rows have changed so we don't copy the entire contents of the table every sync. It compares the current MAX(ORA_ROWSCN) to the MAX(ORA_ROWSCN) that was found on the last sync.

However, the query to determine the MAX (ORA_ROWSCN) is now taking too long. This is a third party database, and we are not able to turn on audit logs.

Is there a reasonable alternative to this ?

Also, we are seeing Oracle timeout on the query to get the MAX(ORA_ROWSCN) is there something we can do to help with this ? We have the max query set at 4 hours, but oracle is still timing out after about 25 minute.

Comment: Can you create a function-based index in the db?  WHat is the client code that is calling this?

Comment: Is there an existing date column that shows last change date (e.g. `MODIFIED_DATE`)? Could you add a date column and a trigger to the source system table?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Using any data column, e.g. MODIFIED_DATE or even a sequence-populated column or identity column isn't sufficient because the rows can be committed out-of-order, and thus row 10000000008 might not exist till after row 10000000009 has been written and read.

Answer (score 0):

A true Change Data Capture (CDC) tool like Oracle GoldenGate could be an alternative depending on your budget (it's not free) and the third party's openness to installing it on their system.  (You would also need to install it on yours.) But, if you're just pulling a few tables every now and then, this probably isn't the best option.  If the data were being transported from Oracle to Oracle, you could potentially use fast refresh materialized views, but SQL Server being in the mix makes things a little trickier.  A grow-your-own solution that uses a trigger on the source table to log inserted/updated/deleted keys to a delta table could be a possibility - but that's only if the third party will allow it on their system.

To reduce query time, you could try using the `/*+PARALLEL(N)*/` hint, which uses N parallel processes to execute the query. But, be aware that this approach will consume additional resources and could slow down the Oracle system.  You'd need to do some trial and error to find the optimal "N" value, a.k.a. DOP or "Degree of Parallelism".  Be conservative when choosing the initial DOP.

Example:

`SELECT /*+PARALLEL(4)*/ MAX(ORA_ROWSCN)
  FROM third_party_table;`

Finally, it would be useful to find out what's actually causing the timeout.  Something in Oracle like a user profile or resource manager plan?  Firewall?  Load balancer?  As a temporary measure, if nothing else, the timeout could be increased.

Comment: "A grow-your-own solution that uses a trigger on the source table to log inserted/updated/deleted keys to a delta table could be a possibility".  OK, once I have the delta table, then what do I do?  I still have to use the pseudo-column ORA_ROWSCN on the delta table to get the data in the order it was committed, and I still can't index that, so the problem from the original question remains.

Comment: Delta table tracks keys that were inserted/updated/deleted in the source table since the last synch — and the last type of DML operation executed on each of those keys. Synch process iterates through each key in the delta table and executes the associated DML on the replica. Processing update operations as upserts obviates keeping track of which columns are changed by update operations.  This only works for tables that have (unique) keys. A key column would need to be added to source tables that don’t have a key. While I’ve seen this approach work, it can hurt performance of the source system.